# Switch statement and Ampersand in condition

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing

if a switch case is given as

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;    
const uint8_t mask = 0x01;
const uint8_t Buffer[];

switch (Buffer[4] & mask)
{
case 0x01U:
---
if
else

case 0x00U:
------
if 
else

default:

}
```

I am doing unit testing in order to get 100% coverage and also test one ureq I need to enter default case but I am not able to understand what switch `(Buffer[2] & mask)` means i.e what exactly the `(Buffer[2] & mask)` describe and `&` is used for what and how can I enter the default case?

Comment: If this code is C or both of `Buffer[4]` and `mask` are primitive type (not class, like `int` or `long`, etc.), `&` is bitwise AND operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `mask` is 1, `Buffer[4] & mask` will be `1` if `Buffer[4]` is an odd number, and `0` if it's even. It **cannot** be anything else.

So the case label `2` is never used.

`&` is the bitwise AND operator.

Comment: Then it ought to be `const mask=0x01;` to make that clear :)

Comment: It does not matter whether `mask` is `const`.  Its value is assigned immediately prior to the `switch` (and the switch is not labeled) so `mask` will always have the assigned value (1) when the switch expression is evaluated.

Comment: Sure, it does not matter *as such*, but I personally like code that communicates intent clearly to me when I read it, and making the variable `const` just makes it clearer and easier to read and also makes it obvious that the value is not intended to be changed later.

Comment: Since the only possible result with mask=0x01 is either  0 or 1, the switch construct should not be used - just use an if/else

Comment: @FredK: Indeed, unless, of course, the *follow-through* behaviour of the `switch` was useful for some reason.